# Pandas - combine columns and put one after another?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have the following dataframe:

```
a1,a2,b1,b2
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
```

The desirable output is:

```
a,b
1,3
2,4
3,5
2,4
3,5
4,6
```

There is a lot of "a" and "b" named headers in the dataframe, the maximum is a50 and b50. So I am looking for the way to combine them all into just "a" and "b".

I think it's possible to do with concat, but I have no idea how to combine it all, putting all the values under each other. I'll be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: so you have a1, a2, a3 till a50 then b1, b2, b3 till b50 in the same order? Meaning that you are having 100 columns?

Comment: Hi. Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we read the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

s = """a1,a2,b1,b2
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=',')
```

Then we stack the columns, and separate the number of the columns from the letter 'a' or 'b':

```py
stacked = df.stack().rename("val").reset_index(1).reset_index()
cols_numbers = pd.DataFrame(stacked
                            .level_1
                            .str.split('(\d)')
                            .apply(lambda l: l[:2])
                            .tolist(), 
                            columns=["col", "num"])
x = cols_numbers.join(stacked[['val', 'index']])
print(x)
```

```
   col num  val  index
0    a   1    1      0
1    a   2    2      0
2    b   1    3      0
3    b   2    4      0
4    a   1    2      1
5    a   2    3      1
6    b   1    4      1
7    b   2    5      1
8    a   1    3      2
9    a   2    4      2
10   b   1    5      2
11   b   2    6      2
```

Finally, we group by `index` and `num` to get two columns `a` and `b`, and we fill the first row of the `b` column with the second value, to get what was expected:

```py
result = (x
         .set_index("col", append=True)
         .groupby(["index", "num"])
         .val
         .apply(lambda g: 
                g
                .unstack()
                .fillna(method="bfill")
                .head(1))
         .reset_index(-1, drop=True))

print(result)
```

```
col          a    b
index num          
0     1    1.0  3.0
      2    2.0  4.0
1     1    2.0  4.0
      2    3.0  5.0
2     1    3.0  5.0
      2    4.0  6.0
```

To get rid of the multiindex at the end: `result.reset_index(drop=True)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long):

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ['a','b'], 'index', 'No').reset_index()[['a','b']]
```

Output:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
3  2  4
4  3  5
5  4  6
```